# Convert multiple excel worksheets to .csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, csv

I found this macro for converting multiple excel worksheet in a workbook to individual named .csv files, but don't know how to remove the workbook name from the converted file name.  I'm sure its simple, but I know nothing about VBA.

```
Sub exportcsv()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", leFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean the *worksheet* name? That's the `& "_" & ws.Name &` part. Now remove that and you'll have 3 files for 3 sheets, all named identically in the same folder. Doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Comment: When I run the macro it is naming the converted file "original file name"_"sheet name".  I need it to just name them sheet name.csv

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv"
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
```

Comment: That gets me close, but not in the same folder I'm converting from.  Perhaps its cause I'm working off the server?  It drops the converted files in my server user directory.